# Finding ASIN with possibly non-unique metadata

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am trying to find the ASINs for individual MP3s in Amazon's store, but I only have data that is likely to be non-unique (title, artist, sometimes the album that the song appears on). Since Amazon's music store does not have 100% coverage, my queries are often returning a large number of spurious results, especially for songs with nondescript titles (e.g. "Rain", "Sunshine", etc.). Are there any tricks I can use when constructing queries to make sure that I only get songs that are exact matches for my data?

Comment: Were you able to find the answer?  If so, can you post it here?

Comment: I was not able to find a simple answer. It might be possible to get it working by parsing through the returned results and discarding those that were obviously wrong (different title, artist, or album), but that does not seem very elegant.